# Ranking Database Entries in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I'm trying to rank the entries in my database, based on the number of times a user saves that term.

So if my table is ,

```
id laptop  Price
1  Macbook $2000
2  MBP     $2300
3  MBP     $2300
4  MBP     $2000
```

The query will return

```
1.) MBP
2.) Macbook
```

I foolishly thought ranking GROUP_BY and DESC would do this, then I tried the @Rank := @Rank +1 approach to no avail. [I must admit, i'm not sure if this is the right way to solve the problem]

```
SET @rank :=0;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT d.*, @rank := @rank + 1
  FROM data d
  ORDER BY d.`laptop`
) d2
WHERE d2.laptop = 'MBP'
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT laptop FROM table
  GROUP BY laptop
  ORDER BY COUNT(laptop) DESC
```

Why won't that work?